# store svn password in gnome-keyring

Tags: linux, svn, gnome-keyring, git-svn

I want to store my svn password in the gnome-keyring so it is encrypted and 'secure'.  I made the necessary changes to ~/.subversion/config, but even after running a few svn commands, I do not see an entry for SVN in the keyring.

What else do I need to do to get SVN using gnome-keyring?  I will also be using this with git-svn.

Comment: What method are you using to access SVN?  SSH, HTTPS, SVNSERVE?

Comment: Note that the entries are labeled just with 'network password' in the keyring, the details should tell if they belong to svn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run git-svn, you may have to build your own Git.  I found [this patch](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg140074.html) to support additional authentication sources.  The patch looks kind of involved, and the post about it is almost a year old.  As far as I can tell though, a) it hasn't made it into Git core yet, and b) Git doesn't seem to have a central issue tracker (!!!!!!) so I don't even know how to suggest that they do so. :(

Answer (score 4):

To run regular SVN with passwords stored in gnome-keyring, your `.subversion/config` should have

```
[auth]
store-passwords=yes
store-auth-creds=yes
password-stores=gnome-keyring
```

and in `.subversion/servers`

```
[global]
store-passwords=yes
store-plaintext-passwords=no
```

There's more if you're using client certificates, but that's the basics.  Then, you need binaries from CollabNet Subversion starting at version 1.6.16 -- the current I think is 1.6.17.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that was what I was missing for SVN; however, for git-svn, I need to do something else.

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed subversion-gnome? It's the GNOME Keyring support for Subversion. You can use a package manager (like yum in fedora) to install it.