# store svn password in gnome-keyring ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, svn, ubuntu-20.04

I want to store the password in the gnome-keyring on ubuntu 20.04. I already tried several solutions from other posts like [store svn password in gnome-keyring](https://superuser.com/questions/312408/store-svn-password-in-gnome-keyring) but it doesn't work. Every time I run a svn command it requires a password.

Can someone please help me?